# Storage Access Framework Audio tab "Media is read-only"

Tags: android, android-sdcard, storage-access-framework

when trying to get a uri to edit an audio file via the Storage Access Framework, if the user selects from the Audio tab, I'm getting a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Media is read-only`.

The SAF is working perfectly for getting a uri to the sdcard root, as well as selecting files from the storage volume itself. However, selecting from the SAF Picker's Audio tab returns a read-only uri. Currently, I have a message that tells users to only select from the volume itself, however my reports show they are still using it fairly often.

This is how I'm currently invoking the SAF picker:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("audio/mpeg");
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_SAF_READ_FILE);
```

According to the Android documentation, when using `Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE`,

> All selected documents are returned to the calling application with persistable read and write permission grants...

-- which is why getting a read-only error is so surprising.

Is there any way for me to get the proper writeable uri? I get that some providers can be read-only, but since this is backed by a file, is there a way I can query the storage volume for the media file pointed to by my read-only uri?

I can get the display name & file size from the read-only uri exposed by the SAF, but according to the docs

> ...it's called "Display Name".  This is provider-specific, and might not necessarily be the file name.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: "is there a way I can query the storage volume for the media file pointed to by my read-only uri?" -- no, mainly because you may not have access to the file. The `MediaStore` (which I presume is what is populating that "Audio" portion of SAF) has access to stuff that you don't (e.g., removable storage). Plus, with Android Q/R, you are losing access to the filesystem more generally.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem. The ideal solution is to be able to tell `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` to restrict the locations to writeable ones -- I filed [a request for this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/133539340).